# is there any way to catch original exception if another exception raise during handeling that in C#?

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch

assume we have following peace of code in C#:

```
try{
  ....
  try{

    throw new Exception1("exception1");

  }catch(Exception exception){

     ...
    throw new Exception2("exception2");

  }
}catch(Exception exception){
    ...
    log(exception.message);
}
```

is it possible in log point(outer catch) to access exception1 object and log that one as well?

Comment: This code doesn't make much sense.  Maybe if you gave us an example from your actual problem domain?

Comment: What you should be doing in *exception2* is `throw new Exception2("exception2", exception)`.  That way, *exception1* is available as the `InnerException` property of *exception2*.  Catching and throwing a new exception with an inner exception is a pretty common pattern

Comment: or, just `throw` without a new exception if it isn't needed

Answer (score 0):

Here are two reasonable examples of what I think you are talking about.  They illustrate what I was trying to describe in the comments as well as what @Jonesopolis describes.

First, my case.  Say you are writing a utility that calls some lower-level service that may throw.  You may want to describe the behavior of the utility in a way that the exceptions that may bubble up have more meaning to the caller.  In this case, I've documented that my utility will throw an `ApplicationException` if there is a problem.

I do this from two places, the first one when I check some pre-conditions (that the path name is neither null or empty and that it is a valid file name (I'm assuming that there is an `IsValidFileName` function I can call)).

But the other place is that if I try to do the operation and it throws (I haven't checked that `File.ReadAllLines` actually ever throws an `IOException`, but I'm guessing it can).  In this case, I don't want to burden my users with catching a possible `IOException`, instead, I translated it into an `ApplicationException` that I document.  I wrap the `IOException` with a catch and throw of my `ApplicationException`, but I include the `IOException` as the *inner exception* so that debugging and tracking down other issues works.  The code looks like:

```
public IEnumerable<string> AccessFile(string pathName)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(pathName) || !IsValidFileName(pathName))
    {
        throw new ApplicationException("Invalid Path Name");
    }

    try
    {
        var result = File.ReadAllLines(pathName);
        return result;
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException("Error Accessing File", ex);
    }
}
```

It's that second parameter to the ApplicationException that sets up the inner exception.  This pattern is *very* common.

---

The other example is what @Jonesopolis describes.

Here I have a work function doing something.  My application architecture demands that I do logging at the level of whatever the `DoSomethingImportant` function is at.  So, it catches any exceptions that get thrown at a lower level.  However, that code wants to bubble up any exceptions to the `DoSomethingImportant` function's caller.  Here, it just uses the `throw` keyword with no argument.  That *rethrows* the current exception and lets it bubble through.

It's important to use `throw;` with no arguments, and not `throw ex;`.  The former allows the existing exception to bubble up.  The latter unwinds the stack at the catch site, and then throws a new exception, losing all the stack information that might point to the faulting location.

This is the typical code that I'm talking about.  It's also a *very* common pattern:

```
public void DoSomethingImportant()
{
    try
    {
        DoSomethingLowLevel();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        GetLogger().Log(ex);
        throw;
    }
}
```